# Почему выражение возвращает False?

Tags: python, python-3.x

В моём понимании `== any([])` возвращает `True`, когда сопоставляемая переменная равна хотя бы чему-то из словаря. Но почему-то переменная `а` со значением `"14"` (то есть и `а[-2:] == "14"`), сопоставляемая со списком, в итоге выдаёт `False`.

Почему и как добиться такой проверки, чтобы если переменная равнялась хоть чему-то из списка, она выдавала `True`?

```
a = input()
print(a[-2:] == any(["11", "14", "13", "12"]))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Ответ:** потому что `"14" != True` !

[из документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

> Return `True` if any element of the iterable is **true**

Все непустые строки при приведении к типу данных `bool` - вернут `True`:

```
In [2]: bool("aaa")
Out[2]: True

In [3]: bool("")
Out[3]: False
```

Как следствие вы сравниваете `a[-2:]` с `True`.

```
In [10]: any(["11", "14", "13", "12"])
Out[10]: True

In [11]: a = "14"

In [12]: a == True
Out[12]: False

In [13]: "14" != True
Out[13]: True
```

---

> Как проверить входит ли значение в список:

```
In [4]: "14" in  ["11", "14", "13", "12"]
Out[4]: True
```

Comment: то есть в моём случае, код должен быть 
"print( a[-2:] in ["11", "14", "13", "12"]"?

Comment: @sensoid, да, попробуйте так...

Answer (score 0):

```
a = input()
l = ["11", "14", "13", "12"]
print(any(k in a for k in l))
```

Думаю, комментарии больше не нужны?

Answer (score 0):

Например, вот так:

```
a = input()
s = ["11", "12", "13", "14"]
if s.count(a[-2:]) > 0:
  print(True)
else:
  print(False)
```

В данном случае мы проверяем, есть ли хоть один совпадающий с переменной **а** элемент списка